# Django Template syntax/tag to filter and check if a related data exists in that model

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on a project with python-3.6.4 and django-2.0.2. For simplicity, I'm explaining the situation in short. Suppose, there are three apps:- "problems", "solve_activities" and "profiles" having three models(mentioned below) inside them. I have a "DetailView" page for each problem. I want to show if the logged in user has solved the problem or not.

The django template tag that I wanted to do use was something like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and problem.solved.all.filter(solver={{user.username}}) %}
```

Here are the above mentioned files:

"problems/models.py":

```
class Problem(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, max_length=100, unique=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

  def get_absoulte_url(self):
    return reverse('problems')
    return reverse('problems:problem_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

I've used the urlpatterns in 'problems/urls.py' as "path('/', views.ProblemDetail.as_view(), name='problem_detail')".

"profiles/models.py"(inherited from auth.models.User):

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

"solve_activities/models.py":

```
class Solve(models.Model):
  problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="solved")
  solver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="solved")
```

**I'm only creating this object when the user solves a problem.**

Now, my ProblemDetail view on problems/views.py:

```
class ProblemDetail(generic.DetailView):
  model = Problem
  template_name = 'problems/problem_detail.html'
```

And the "problems/problem_detail.html" file where I'm facing the complexity basically:

```
<h1>{{problem}}</h1>
<h4>Solve Status: {% if user.is_authenticated and problem.solved.all.filter(solver={{user.username}}) %}Solved{% else %}Unsolved{% endif %}</h4>
```

Again,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and problem.solved.all.filter(solver={{user.username}}) %}
```

is what I want to do, but I couldn't find any useful resource on how to do it correctly.

The error it's raising is:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /problems/timus-1000/
Could not parse the remainder: '(solver={{user}})' from 'problem.solved.all.filter(solver={{user}})'
```

Comment: You can't call methods e.g. `.filter(...)` in the Django template language. You can either write a [custom template filter or tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/), or override `get_context_data` for your view and calculate `solved_status` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont do logic in templates, thats what views are for. Add it to the context and use it in the template.

```
class ProblemDetail(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProblemDetail, self).get_context_data()
        context["solve_status"] = self.request.user.is_authenticated and context["object"].solved.filter(solver=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
```

then in the template use

```
{% if solve_status %} ..
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.
It's giving this error message now:

`
get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/problems/timus-1000/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'`

Comment: Sorry i was a bit fast, change to.
    `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: I've written this:

`    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProblemDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["solve_status"] = self.request.user.is_authenticated and Problem.objects.filter(solved__solver=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
`

which is showing this error now: " Cannot query "msabeer" **(which was my username)** : Must be "Problem" instance." 

I'm just a beginner currently, I'm sorry.

Comment: ok to find if the user has solved the current problem use `Solve.objects.filter(solver=self.request.user, problem=context["object"]).exists()`

Comment: Finally!!! Thank you a lot :D I really appreciate it. The last query worked properly and just to let you know, the previous one worked but it was returning always true. Can you explain why?